# Average using SQL Group by needs to omit duplicates and group by more than one column

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and I'm having an issue grouping by more than one col and finding an average while omitting duplicate rows.  I have a transaction table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CUST_TRANSACTION](  
     [EXTRACT_DATE] [date] NULL,
     [CUSTOMER_ID] [bigint] NULL,   
     [TRANS_NUMBER] [bigint] NULL,
     [CATEGORY] [smallint] NULL,    
     [RANKING] [smallint] NULL )
```

Here is some data:

```
EXTRACT_DATE    CUSTOMER_ID TRANS_NUMBER    CATEGORY    RANKING
10/31/2017          10001   1000101              4  100
10/31/2017          10001   1000102              4  100
10/31/2017          10002   1000201              4  200
10/31/2017          10001   1000103              5  100
10/31/2017          10003   1000301              5  300
10/31/2017          10003   1000302              5  300
10/31/2017          10004   1000401              7  500
10/31/2017          10001   1000104              8  100
```

The Customer_Id AND TRANS_NUMBER combo needs to be unique, but a customer_id can have 1 to Many Trans_Numbers and a Customer_Id can exist in 1 to many Categories.  From the data I reviewed, the Ranking for a Customer_ID seems to be the same for a given EXTRACT_DATE.  I found no NULLS in the Ranking, but I did find zeroes, so I need to exclude any zeroes from the Average.

The request is to generate a report broken down by each Category ( 1 - 15) and find the Average Ranking within that Category, but to only count a customer_id once and also find the Max Ranking with that Category.  This is for a given EXTRACT_Date.

So I ran the following:

```
Select CATEGORY, MAX(RANKING) "Max Ranking", AVG(RANKING) "Average Ranking"
from CUST_TRANSACTION 
where  EXTRACT_DATE = Convert(datetime, '2017-10-31' )
     and RANKING > 1
group by CATEGORY
order by CATEGORY
```

Generated the following output:

```
CATEGORY    Max Ranking Average Ranking 
4                 200   133 
5                 300   233 
7                 500   500 
8                 100   100
```

But Category 4 should have an Average of 150 since customer_Id = 10001 has two entries and Category 5 should be = 200 since Customer_id 10003 has two entries.

When I tried to Group by both Category, Customer_Id, the output includes each combination of Category and Customer_Id, which is what Group by does.  So I'm not sure if I need a sub-select or any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you don't care about the trans_number mappings, so you could remove it and choose distinct remaining values in a derived table:

```
Select CATEGORY, MAX(RANKING) "Max Ranking", AVG(RANKING) "Average Ranking"
from ( select distinct [EXTRACT_DATE] ,
                [CUSTOMER_ID] ,
                [CATEGORY] ,
                [RANKING] from CUST_TRANSACTION )CUST_TRANSACTION
where  EXTRACT_DATE = Convert(datetime, '2017-10-31' )
     and RANKING > 1
group by CATEGORY
order by CATEGORY
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked great.  I was thinking I needed a sub-select, but I was struggling with putting it together with the where clause & Group by.  You are correct, I am not concerned with the trans_number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Common Table Expression (CTE) to filter out duplicate customerID in a category. Something like this.

```
;with cte as (
select CATEGORY, RANKING, EXTRACT_DATE
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by category, customer_id order by customer_id) rn
from CUST_TRANSACTION
)
Select CATEGORY, MAX(RANKING) "Max Ranking", AVG(RANKING) "Average Ranking"
from cte --CUST_TRANSACTION 
where  EXTRACT_DATE = Convert(datetime, '2017-10-31' )
     and RANKING > 1
and rn = 1
group by CATEGORY
order by CATEGORY
```

Comment: Thanks - this also worked.  I was reading about over & partition and need to mess around with them a bit to better understand them.

Answer (score 0):

Due to different requirements of overall average and maximum you can't use a single column to get both.  A sub-select will deliver one column for averaging and another for maximum'ing.

```
DECLARE @QUERY_DATE DATE = '2017-10-31';

Select 
    CATEGORY
    , MAX(RANKING_detail_max) "Max Ranking"
    , AVG(RANKING_detail_sum) "Average Ranking"
from (
  select CATEGORY
       , CUSTOMER_ID
       , SUM(RANKING) RANKING_detail_sum
       , MAX(RANKING) RANKING_detail_max
  from CUST_TRANSACTION 
  where EXTRACT_DATE = @QUERY_DATE
    and RANKING > 0
  group by CATEGORY, CUSTOMER_ID
) rollup
group by CATEGORY
order by CATEGORY
```